# Can I extend a function based view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view from a third party app whose signature looks like this:

```
@secure_required
def activate(request, activation_key,
             template_name='userena/activate_fail.html',
             retry_template_name='userena/activate_retry.html',
             success_url=None, extra_context=None):
```

How do I extend this function in a clean manner? I actually only need to provide some of the optional parameters, but can I do this without copying the entire function in to my code to override it? This seems like it would not be safe in the future when I upgrade versions of this third party app, since their code could change.

**Edit:**

If I try to just override the URL to include an extra parameter, it says the view received an unexpected parameter.

Here is the URL override I am doing:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
    userena_views.activate,
    success_url='/foo/', name='userena_activate',),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable-length arguments:

```
def my_activate(request, *args, **kwargs):
    res = activate(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # Do stuff you need to do
    return res
```

---

Specifically to your problem, I think, in your URL definition, you should be passing `success_url` in a dictionary:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
    userena_views.activate,
    {'success_url': '/foo/'}, name='userena_activate',),
```

(Just a guess, that's usually how additional parameters are passed to view functions.)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could wrap and return the function like that. However, I don't even need to go that far - I just want to add extra_context or a success_url, but the view is saying it receives an unexpected parameter.

Comment: I think `success_url` should be a dictionary. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you